# What field type we can use in mongo to store an array of objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

What field type we can use in mongo to store an array of objects?. I wanted to store the data below .I have my implementation below and i have added the code maybe you can check it somehow and let me know where is the part where i got an issue or error. I have also provided the sample data. The issue with the current implementation is it does not save the data the books array in the databse is 0 elements

## Sample data

```
{
    "books":
              [
                {
                    "title": "Professional JavaScript",
                    "authors": [
                        "Nicholas C. Zakas"
                    ],
                    "edition": 3,
                    "year": 2011
                },
                {
                    "title": "Professional JavaScript",
                    "authors": [
                        "Nicholas C.Zakas"
                    ],
                    "edition": 2,
                    "year": 2009
                }
               
              ]
}

#implementation


const schema = new Schema({
    books: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }]

  })


var RouterData = mongoose.model('RouterData', schema);

var routerData = {
    "books":
              [
                {
                    "title": "Professional JavaScript",
                    "authors": [
                        "Nicholas C. Zakas"
                    ],
                    "edition": 3,
                    "year": 2011
                },
                {
                    "title": "Professional JavaScript",
                    "authors": [
                        "Nicholas C.Zakas"
                    ],
                    "edition": 2,
                    "year": 2009
                }

              ]
}

var data = new RouterData({routerData: routerData});
data.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define the schema like this.

```js
const booksSchema = new Schema({
  books: [{
    title: String,
    authors: [String],
    edition: Number,
    year: { type: Date }
  }]
})
```

Comment: I have updated my question i have provided my sample code above , thank you

Comment: I think instead of this line ```var data = new RouterData({routerData: routerData});```, You should do : ```var data = new RouterData({...routerData});```

Comment: You are setting the key `routerData` which is not a part of your schema. You need to provide the same data format that you have in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Define your schema in mongoose like this:

```
const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    authors: [String],
    edition: Number,
    year: Number,
}, {
    _id: false,
});

const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    books: [BookSchema],
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question i have provided my sample code above , thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose then you should do in your schema

```
books: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }]
```

mixed means that it can take anything object, array etc. you can check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed

Comment: I have updated my question i have provided my sample code above , thank you

Comment: Have you check the link? Now to save in your service add data to your books by using **push** method because its an array before you save. eg **books.push(data)** then **books.save()** data is the req.body or your payload

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  authors: [String],
  edition: { type: Number },
  year: { type: Number },
});

const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  books: [BookSchema],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('MySchema', MySchema);
```